# How to display ACF plugin fields in several pages

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a group of fields in ACF plugin and this group belongs only to one page (for example page-contacts.php), but I want to display this group of field on several pages (for example page-main.php). Here is repeater field loop which is on the page-contact.php.

```
<?php if( have_rows('slider') ): ?>
    <div id = "events-slider">
    <?php while( have_rows('slider') ): the_row(); ?>
         <div class = "events-slider__slide">
            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" alt>
         </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

How can I use this loop on page-main.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a field from another page, you can add the pages ID as a second parameter :

```
have_rows($field_name, $post_id);
```

Then you just need the post ID from the page, where the correct content is held -

Good luck!